# Registering Custom Spring Cloud Task with Spring Cloud Data Flow

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

I'm getting started with Spring Cloud Data Flow and want to implement a simple Spring Cloud Task I want to use with it.

I created a [hello world example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-task/docs/2.0.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-developing-first-task) from the documentation. When I run it in my IDE it executes without any problems and prints 'hello world'. It is using the following JDBC connection:

> o.s.j.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource  : Creating new JDBC Driver Connection to [jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false]

I use the dockerized Local Spring Data Flow Server which uses the following JDBC connection for its metadata:

> o.s.c.d.s.config.web.WebConfiguration    : Starting H2 Server with URL: jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:19092/mem:dataflow

When I deploy my task to the server and start it I get the following exception:

> org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'taskLifecycleListener'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid TaskExecution, ID 1 not found

This is because the Task and the server use different H2 databases. I somehow cannot override the database configuration of the task. I have H2 in the classpath and the following application.yml configuration to match the server:

```
spring:
  datasource:
      url: jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:19092/mem:dataflow
      username: sa
      password:
      driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
```

It never gets applied. It always uses the preconfigured `jdbc:h2:mem:testdb`-connection. How can I get this to run?

Answer (score 1):

This exception indicates that the task did not connect to the datastore that is being used by dataflow.Apparently you're using the default database of Spring Cloud Data Flow.
I invite you to do this:

- add the following dependency in the pom.xml of your task:

  ```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
      <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  ```
- if the previous tips din't work. Use the spring initailizr with the 1.5.14 version of Spring boot + the previous step
- If it still doesn't work try to [override the database configuration of Spring cloud DataFlow](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.5.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-rdbms) + add the corresponding dependency in the pom.xml of your task

I hope it will help

Comment: Your incremental approach to troubleshooting it, is spot-on. Nice!

Comment: Thank you, i'll try to carry on!

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I omitted `@EnableTask` on the task class so that there is just the `@SpringBootApplication` and it works on the Data Flow server, but I don't know why.