# Spring cloud Dataflow Failed to start bean 'taskLifecycleListener'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid TaskExecution

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

I'm trying to execute a simple Spring Cloud Task hello world example(https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-task/docs/2.0.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-developing-first-task) in a custom Spring Cloud Dataflow Server local that uses oracle database dependency and I'm getting this error during it's execution:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-10-22 10:27:02.246 ERROR 21996 --- [           main] o.s.c.t.listener.TaskLifecycleListener   : An event to end a task has been received for a task that has not yet started.
2020-10-22 10:27:02.253 ERROR 21996 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'taskLifecycleListener'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid TaskExecution, ID 43 not found
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:185) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:53) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:360) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:158) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:122) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:894) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:553) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) [spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at com.edf.fr.scdftaskexample.ScdfTaskExampleApplication.main(ScdfTaskExampleApplication.java:23) [classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [scdf-task-example-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [scdf-task-example-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51) [scdf-task-example-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52) [scdf-task-example-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid TaskExecution, ID 43 not found
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:198) ~[spring-core-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.task.listener.TaskLifecycleListener.doTaskStart(TaskLifecycleListener.java:244) ~[spring-cloud-task-core-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.task.listener.TaskLifecycleListener.start(TaskLifecycleListener.java:366) ~[spring-cloud-task-core-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:182) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
```

Here's the code for the main application:

```
package com.edf.fr.scdftaskexample;

import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.task.configuration.EnableTask;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTask
public class ScdfTaskExampleApplication{
    
     

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(){
        return new HelloWorldCommandLineRunner();
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ScdfTaskExampleApplication.class, args);
    }

     public static class HelloWorldCommandLineRunner implements CommandLineRunner {

         
        @Override
        public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("Hello world!!");
        }

     }
     
     
    
}
```

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@infra-dbaas-vm010.noe.edf.fr:1521/DBST000J_S.noe.edf.fr
spring.datasource.username=happydap
spring.datasource.password=Droopydap9*
spring.datasource.driver.class=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
logging.level.org.springframework.cloud.task=DEBUG
spring.application.name=helloWorld
```

Here's the pom.xml for the Spring Cloud Task:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.edf.fr</groupId>
    <artifactId>scdf-task-example</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>scdf-task-example</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Cloud Dataflow Task</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR8</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-task</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${​​spring-cloud.version}​​</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>



</project>
```

And the pom.xml of my custom dataflow server:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>custom-dataflow-server-maven</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>custom-dataflow-server</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR4</spring-cloud.version>
        <spring-cloud-dataflow.version>2.5.1.RELEASE</spring-cloud-dataflow.version>
        <spring-security-oauth2.version>2.3.7.RELEASE</spring-security-oauth2.version>
        <oracle.version>11.2.0.3</oracle.version>
        <kubernetes-client.version>4.1.0</kubernetes-client.version>
        <nimbus-jose-jwt.version>8.17</nimbus-jose-jwt.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-dataflow-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security-oauth2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
            <artifactId>kubernetes-client</artifactId>
            <version>${kubernetes-client.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
            <artifactId>nimbus-jose-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>${nimbus-jose-jwt.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dataflow-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud-dataflow.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-release</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

Am I missing some configuration here. How can I get this to run? Thanks.

Comment: please show your application.properties and your task configuration

Comment: application.properties:
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@infra-dbaas-vm010.noe.edf.fr:1521/DBST000J_S.noe.edf.fr
spring.datasource.username=happydap
spring.datasource.password=Droopydap9*
spring.datasource.driver.class=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
logging.level.org.springframework.cloud.task=DEBUG
spring.application.name=helloWorld

What's a task configuration ?

Comment: please edit your question and add the application.properties. I mean TaskConfigurer

Comment: Edited my question to include application.properties. I don't know what a taskConfigurer is.

Answer (score 1):

It's about SCDF's database, basically, if your SCDF works well, and your task cannot run due to the error

> Invalid TaskExecution, ID 43 not found

Meaning your task application does not connect to the SCDF's database, so It cannot get the Task Execution ID, you might need to check your database driver (add jar library) or check the task application if it points to SCDF's database

The issue below might link to your issue

[How to properly compile/package a Task for Spring Cloud Data Flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62887534/how-to-properly-compile-package-a-task-for-spring-cloud-data-flow/68601723#68601723)